# Django-cms: Front-end editor not synced to content in admin site

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a newly constructed Django project on a windows machine and am using django-cms. I have started populating the home page content using Django-CMS's front-end editor. Everything uploads properly and saves; however, when I try and view the content through the admin site it is not there. The placeholder tags appear but the plugins and content within the placeholders do not. Likewise, when I try adding plug-ins and content from the backend, the front-end does not display them. It appears that something is out of sync; however, I cant figure out how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need information of Python version, Django version and Django CMS version.

Did you try to add content through admin?

Comment: Python 2.7 and Django 1.3. I did try adding content from the admin. It saves but does not show up on the front end.

Comment: woops... and Django-CMS 2.1.3

Comment: I suggest you to use Django==1.2.5 with Django-CMS. For now 1.3 is not fully supported, and for production better use prooven setup. 

I use Django==1.2.5 + Django-CMS 2.1.3 - quite stable.

Comment: Thanks Kee... It turned out to be a database issue that I just resolved. I am now using Django==1.2.5 and everything is running fine.